# jQuery fadeMe is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put a `fadeOut()` inside a function, so I can use it at various places in the script. I'm having a problem getting it to work, even though this should have worked. This is the error I get from Firebug:

`TypeError: $(...).html(...).parent(...).fadeIn(...).fadeMe is not a function`

```
success: function(x) {

    if(x["s"] == false) {

    $('.errors').html(x['m']).parent().fadeIn().fadeMe(); // i'm stuck here

    } else if(x["s"] == true) {
        // other code
    }
},

function fadeMe(){
    setTimeout(function() { $(".errors").fadeOut(); }, 5000)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to use `setTimeout` instead:

```
$('.errors').delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

**References**

[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: I put that code in the function, and still get the same error. I'm trying to keep this in a function so I don't need to repeat it at several places.

Comment: From your code seems that in success of asynchronous call you try to fade in and after 5 secs fade out the parent div. This should work if everything else is correct. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/ah7ap0dy/3/

Comment: You're correct. But I need help with putting it in a function, since I wont have to repeat `$('.errors').delay(5000).fadeOut();` when it's needed at other places in the page, and I can simply call the function. Do you know how to do it the way I have? Can you help with the `fadeMe is not a function` error?

Comment: It is outside the ajax call.